# Guaranteed locales on different platforms

Tags: c++, linux, windows, macos, localization

Are there any locales besides the default C Locale that are guaranteed to exist or at least installed by default on the end-users computer on windows Linux or macOSX?
I use boost property tree which can read XML from a file and takes a locale as a parameter. If I want to write a cross-platform application and the file is in german and utf-8 encoded, which locale should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not guarantee locale, but C (and this just in POSIX).

Various Linux distributions allow you to choose the locale to install, and usually it install just the country (and region) locale (now the UTF8 variant). So no, there is not way. And I would not expect anything useful on that: locale names are not so standardized (but now we have a RFC, OTOH that RFC is not about installed locales).

But there is a Unicode for this ;-)

Unicode Consortium publish own locale definitions: http://cldr.unicode.org/index, and you may look for libraries using this project. And this solve a lot more problems, e.g. Python do not use locales for all functions, so you may get wrong localized data.

On the other hand, I think you are over-engineering (or looking the wrong problem).

Locale is a user choice, so respect user choice. Try to use German UTF8 locale. You should expect that such local is installed on computer where users expect German text.

If user doesn't have a German locale, probably do not expect to have localized numbers and dates, so just ignore it (so let's the system to pick the correct default, which uses should expect).  Note: on my systems, I use DK locale for dates, because I like much better the ISO notation (2020-11-26) instead of German date. On Windows I tend to select ',' as list separator (and not ';', because it is handy, and so I can copy-paste excel formulas). I expect programs to respect my locale choice, not to choose their locale.

Obviously there are exceptions (ans do the first part of the answer): you serve data for users (e.g. web servers), so you care system local only for system messages (and logs), not for the serving data.  Or programs to learn languages (it may not be expected to have locale installed, for beginning lesson, but probably one need anyway to install the correct locale, just because the need to type Umlauts (German), or Kanji (Japanese).

So: for cross platform programs, just use what users expect, so initialize the locale which users selected. So uses localized dates, numbers. But do not force a locale.  If you need to serve data to external people (like webservers), use CLDR (system locales are... not so good for such task).

Comment: Are you sure about the POSIX part in "There is not guarantee locale, but C (and this just in POSIX)"? Cppreference says about std::locale::classic the follwing: "Obtains a reference to the C++ locale that implements the classic "C" locale semantics. This locale, unlike the global locale, cannot be altered". This sounds like there's always a "C" Locale in a standard conformant implementation.

Comment: yeah. `C` is the only locale guaranteed by POSIX